# How to remap the arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have an old Dell Inspiron 1050 laptop whose keyboard's right arrow key is not working.

Earlier when I was on windows 8.1 I used `sharpkeys` to remap:

- the down arrow to right arrow,
- the left arrow to down arrow
- the menu key to left arrow.

I am new to Ubuntu so *how would I remap the keys in Ubuntu the same way as in Windows above?*
i am using ubuntu 14.2 LTS

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 1):

hy Aabir,
I was also searching for the same this resource helped me and I could remap my key on my linux mint netbook.
[remap keys in linux](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/)

Comment: Hi and welcome on AskUbuntu.com :-) You could strongly improve your answer by giving a quick summary of the solution you linked to, instead of just providing the URL. That short link-only answers are not really liked to be seen here...